# i keep getting this error in python (spyder) and i have no idea how to solve it , index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, scipy

im trying to estimate the gjr garch model using this code below and the dataset im using is the bitcoin returns (daily) total of 1600 observations. im getting this error ''index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1''. and above it it says :

File "C:\Users\georgios\Downloads\untitled1.py", line 97, in 
estimates = fmin_slsqp(gjr_garch_likelihood, startingVals,

File "C:\Users\georgios\Nieuwe map\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 207, in fmin_slsqp
res = _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, bounds=bounds,

File "C:\Users\georgios\Nieuwe map\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 375, in _minimize_slsqp
sf = _prepare_scalar_function(func, x, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,

File "C:\Users\georgios\Nieuwe map\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 261, in _prepare_scalar_function
sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,

File "C:\Users\georgios\Nieuwe map\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_differentiable_functions.py", line 136, in **init**
self._update_fun()

File "C:\Users\georgios\Nieuwe map\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_differentiable_functions.py", line 226, in _update_fun
self._update_fun_impl()

File "C:\Users\georgios\Nieuwe map\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_differentiable_functions.py", line 133, in update_fun
self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)

File "C:\Users\georgios\Nieuwe map\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_differentiable_functions.py", line 130, in fun_wrapped
return fun(x, *args)

File "C:\Users\georgios\Downloads\untitled1.py", line 21, in gjr_garch_likelihood
sigma2[t] = (omega + alpha * eps[t-1]**2

File "C:\Users\georgios\Nieuwe map\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 977, in **setitem**
values[key] = value

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

My dataset is fine from
What I see , I only have one excel file with only one column with the returns
And the garch model is Univariate

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import size, log, pi, sum, array, zeros, diag, mat, asarray, sqrt, \
    copy
from numpy.linalg import inv
from scipy.optimize import fmin_slsqp

def gjr_garch_likelihood(parameters, data, sigma2, out=None):
    ''' Returns negative log-likelihood for GJR-GARCH(1,1,1) model.'''
    mu = parameters[0]
    omega = parameters[1]
    alpha = parameters[2]
    gamma = parameters[3]
    beta = parameters[4]
    
    T = size(data,0)
    eps = data - mu
    # Data and sigma2 are T by 1 vectors
    for t in range(1,T):
        sigma2[t] = (omega + alpha * eps[t-1]**2 
                     + gamma * eps[t-1]**2 * (eps[t-1]<0) + beta * sigma2[t-1])
    
    logliks = 0.5*(log(2*pi) + log(sigma2) + eps**2/sigma2)
    loglik = sum(logliks)
    
    if out is None:
        return loglik
    else:
        return loglik, logliks, copy(sigma2)
    
def gjr_constraint(parameters, data, sigma2, out=None):
    ''' Constraint that alpha+gamma/2+beta<=1'''
    
    alpha = parameters[2]
    gamma = parameters[3]
    beta = parameters[4]

    return array([1-alpha-gamma/2-beta])

def hessian_2sided(fun, theta, args):
    f = fun(theta, *args)
    h = 1e-5*np.abs(theta)
    thetah = theta + h
    h = thetah - theta
    K = size(theta,0)
    h = np.diag(h)
    
    fp = zeros(K)
    fm = zeros(K)
    for i in range(K):
        fp[i] = fun(theta+h[i], *args)
        fm[i] = fun(theta-h[i], *args)
        
    fpp = zeros((K,K))
    fmm = zeros((K,K))
    for i in range(K):
        for j in range(i,K):
            fpp[i,j] = fun(theta + h[i] + h[j],  *args)
            fpp[j,i] = fpp[i,j]
            fmm[i,j] = fun(theta - h[i] - h[j],  *args)
            fmm[j,i] = fmm[i,j]
            
    hh = (diag(h))
    hh = hh.reshape((K,1))
    hh = hh @ hh.T
    
    H = zeros((K,K))
    for i in range(K):
        for j in range(i,K):
            H[i,j] = (fpp[i,j] - fp[i] - fp[j] + f 
                       + f - fm[i] - fm[j] + fmm[i,j])/hh[i,j]/2
            H[j,i] = H[i,j]
    
    return H

# Import data
FTSEreturn = pd.read_csv('1.csv')


# Starting values
startingVals = array([FTSEreturn.mean(),
                      FTSEreturn.var() * .01,
                      .03, .09, .90])


# Estimate parameters
finfo = np.finfo(np.float64)
bounds = [(-10*FTSEreturn.mean(), 10*FTSEreturn.mean()),
          (finfo.eps, 2*FTSEreturn.var() ),
          (0.0,1.0), (0.0,1.0), (0.0,1.0)]
       
T = FTSEreturn.shape[0]
sigma2 = T * FTSEreturn.var()
# Pass a NumPy array, not a pandas Series
args = (np.asarray(FTSEreturn), sigma2)
estimates = fmin_slsqp(gjr_garch_likelihood, startingVals,
                       f_ieqcons=gjr_constraint, bounds = bounds,
                       args = args)

loglik, logliks, sigma2final = gjr_garch_likelihood(estimates, FTSEreturn,
                                                    sigma2, out=True)

step = 1e-5 * estimates
scores = zeros((T,5))
for i in range(5):
    h = step[i]
    delta = np.zeros(5)
    delta[i] = h
    
    loglik, logliksplus, sigma2 = gjr_garch_likelihood(estimates + delta, \
                               np.asarray(FTSEreturn), sigma2, out=True)
    loglik, logliksminus, sigma2 = gjr_garch_likelihood(estimates - delta, \
                              np.asarray(FTSEreturn), sigma2, out=True)                   
               
    scores[:,i] = (logliksplus - logliksminus)/(2*h)

I = (scores.T @ scores)/T

J = hessian_2sided(gjr_garch_likelihood, estimates, args)
J = J/T
Jinv = mat(inv(J))
vcv = Jinv*mat(I)*Jinv/T
vcv = asarray(vcv)

output = np.vstack((estimates,sqrt(diag(vcv)),estimates/sqrt(diag(vcv)))).T    
print('Parameter   Estimate       Std. Err.      T-stat')
param = ['mu','omega','alpha','gamma','beta']
for i in range(len(param)):
    print('{0:<11} {1:>0.6f}        {2:0.6f}    {3: 0.5f}'.format(param[i],
           output[i,0], output[i,1], output[i,2]))
```

any help would be appreciated because im stuck on this one month now and i cant solve it

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: There isn’t really much to print other than the model parameters, which is what the likelihood function does which probably gives the error

Comment: and you should print them to check if you use them in correct way - if you use `eps[t-1]` then first you could print `t, t-1, len(eps)` to see if you use correct value in `eps[t-1]` - and maybe you would see that you use wrong values - and this gives your error `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`. You would see that `len(eps)`  gives `1` and this means that you can use only `eps[0]` but you `t-1` gives `1` and you have `esp[1]` - and this is mistake

Answer (score 0):

The error says there's an indexing error during a `setitem` in

```
sigma2[t] = (omega + alpha * eps[t-1]**2
```

In other words, `t` is too large for the array `sigma2`.

That's in the `gjr_garch_likelihood` function.  `t` is an iterator that starts at `1`.  `sigma2` is an argument.  So we need to look at how the function is called, and the corresponding argument is.

That's more complicated, since it's a function used by `fmin_slsqp`.  So the next step is to review that function's docs, to understand how it calls the `func`, and especially what arguments it provides to your `gjr...`.  I won't do that for you!

But it's a good idea when encountering errors like this to add some diagnostic prints to your `gjr...` function.  You need to clearly understand what gets passed to it, paying particular attention to array shapes.  Don't make assumptions.  Verify.

You may need to change `gjr ...` to accomodate the arguments, or you may need to modify how you call `fmin...`.

Question - how much of this did you already figure out in the past month of struggle?  If you already figured this out, you should have included that information in the question.